# How to set minDate for flatpickr/Ninja Forms?

Tags: wordpress, datepicker, flatpickr

I kinda asked this question already but have not gotten a solution, so I am giving this another try...

I am using the WordPress Plugin ninja forms and have a datepicker. I want to disable any past dates, so that the user can only select the present or future dates in the datepicker.

I googled this a lot but from what I am understanding most posts about this won't work anymore since Ninja Forms changed its datepicker plugin from pikaday to flatpickr.

I know that I need to set "minDate" to today but I don't know how to select the datepicker field. I am attaching a screenshot of the HTML that the plugin produces. If anyone can help me with this, that would very much appreciated!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the settings in javascript like in this documentation: [Flatpickr documentation](https://flatpickr.js.org/examples/#disabling-dates)

But I'm facing the same issue because I can't make this code work on my site. I think it's the loading order or something like that... Anyway, hope this will help you!